# android GPS BroadCastReceiver for up Api 26

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying handle detect When Gps on/of,When I use below codes,it works until Api 26,but in Android 8.0 and Android 9.0 doesn't work.How can I fix code to provide working in android 8.0 and 9.0?

GpsLocationReceiver class

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (isGpsEnabled || isNetworkEnabled) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "in android.location.PROVIDERS_OPen",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                // Handle Location turned OFF
                Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, AlertMessage.class);
                pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(pushIntent);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifests

```
<receiver android:name=".service.GpsLocationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of android Oreo, there has been a limitation on receiving implicit broadcasts due to resource consumption considerations.

> Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. An implicit broadcast is a broadcast that does not target that app specifically. For example, ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED is an implicit broadcast, since it is sent to all registered listeners, letting them know that some package on the device was replaced. However, ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is not an implicit broadcast, since it is sent only to the app whose package was replaced, no matter how many other apps have registered listeners for that broadcast.

So if you register your broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in the manifest, they won't receive anything on devices with Android 8.0 or higher. (Except for broadcasts listed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html))

instead you can use `Context.registerReceiver()` to register your receivers which as long as the context you register them on exists, will receive the broadcasts.

You can find more info in the [official document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will use Context.registerReceiver() in our onCreate ,is it right? When I use onCreate method, it can't be run When device boot.

Comment: Using `Context.registerReceiver()`, you will only receive the broadcasts as long as the context is still alive! So if you do this in `onCreate` of an activity for example, you have to unregister it in `onDestroy` of the activity to prevent `leaked broadcast receiver` error.